# Is there a better way than repeating --build-arg on the command line when building a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker

My single `docker build` command line is getting quite long. I wonder if there's a better way than settings all the `ARG`'s in the Dockerfile and then `--build-arg` through each of them on the `docker build` command.

Comment: You could use docker-compose to build your image. Arguments would be specified under build: -> args: (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args). I doubt there's much else except shell tricks.

Comment: @sneep I was avoiding docker-compose bc I thought it was for use-cases involving multiple images. Is that not the case?

Comment: I'll look into it.

Comment: I guess that's the use case, but even if I had only one container to build, if the build command line was kind of complex I'd maybe use docker-compose. Or more likely I'd store the command in a file somewhere and not worry about the command line being too long :p That's just me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there are no built-in possibility to specify file with build args to use `docker build` yet.

But anyway we can use simple bash wrapper for that:

**1.** We create file with build args. Something like `args_list`:

```
month=March
day=26
year=2018
```

**2.** An example of the `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM alpine:3.7
ARG month
ARG day
ARG year
RUN echo "Today is the $day/$month/$year."
```

**3.** And build our above docker image with the following one line script:

```
command="docker build ."; for i in $(cat args_list); do command+=" --build-arg $i"; done; $command
```

The output shows that everything is successfully injected:

```
 Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/5 : FROM alpine:3.7
 ---> 3fd9065eaf02
Step 2/5 : ARG month
 ---> Running in 5c6e695c3fab
Removing intermediate container 5c6e695c3fab
 ---> 6193d0d5665f
Step 3/5 : ARG day
 ---> Running in da0bc3e65890
Removing intermediate container da0bc3e65890
 ---> 41a90a4dd893
Step 4/5 : ARG year
 ---> Running in 83f6ae68390d
Removing intermediate container 83f6ae68390d
 ---> 1fd4beef3c53
Step 5/5 : RUN echo "Today is the $day/$month/$year."
 ---> Running in b5eaa6a5a80c
Today is the 26/March/2018.
Removing intermediate container b5eaa6a5a80c
 ---> de7581671706
Successfully built de7581671706
```

This way we can simply add new build args into the "build args" file and our CI system will build proper images without changes on its side.